# Angular Route doesn't work (no error)

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am new to Angular and I need help with UI Router. I need to load mylink.html after clicking on link. Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('hollywood', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});
$stateProvider.state('mylink', {
templateUrl: 'mylink.html'
});
})

<a ui-sref="mylink">My Link</a>
<article ui-view></article>
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no error in console, except error after click:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load .... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

The thing is file is local and I don't think I can set up CORS in these case.

https://jsfiddle.net/2q61mcp9/

Comment: you missed to add url in state object

Comment: What should I put in url? I saw tutorials and not always people need url. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
  var app = angular.module('hollywood', ['ui.router']);
  app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });
    $stateProvider.state('mylink', {
      url: '/my-link',
      templateUrl: 'mylink.html' // give absolute url like src/views/mylink/html
    });
  })
```

You missed to add url in state object

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. It work's half-correctly when I run it in Electron but in browser it doesn't work at all.
In Electron app I click on "mylink" and it loads my HTML file but when I click another "mylink2" it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

@Damian Are you serving your angular app via some kind of server (python ,node etc), or are you simply running the app via file system(Directly via open with browser option) in browser ? 
If you are directly running it you are most likely to get this `CORS` issue as browsers dont allow resource sharing via file system for security issues.

Comment: I use it directly on my localhost. When I run it in Electron (chrominium+nodejs) I don't have problem with loading files. But still have problem with routing. It works only once.

Answer (score 0):

My code is correct. I've deleted 'url' and run it on server. It work's.